# MS Word VBA: How to add text at a specific location in each row of a table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my first VBA macro in Word. I am trying to add parenthesis at a specific location, in each row of a table, in all the tables of the active document.I want an open parens at character 4 in each row and a close parens at character location 6 likewise. How do I do this? Here is my code so far. Am I using the right functions?

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim x As Integer, j As Integer, i As Integer, S As String
For j = 1 To 2
    
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(j)
        x = ActiveDocument.Tables(j).Rows.Count
            For i = 1 To x
                ActiveDocument.Tables(j).Rows(i).Select
                ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="("
            
            
            Next i
        End With
Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: @jonsson  Each cell in the row. Yes, cell1 should be  "abc(d)efgh" and cell 2 should be "ijk(l)mnopq" . Sorry for the confusion, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content is really simple (text, no formatting), you could start with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertbraces1()
Dim cn As Long
Dim tn As Long

With ActiveDocument.Content
  For tn = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Tables(tn).Range
      For cn = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(cn)
          ' assume we only want to insert () if there are more than 3 characters in the cell
          ' the cell's range contains am emd of cell marker, ChrW(13) & ChrW(7)
          If Len(.Range.Text) > 5 Then
            .Range.Text = Left(.Range.Text, 3) & "(" & Mid(.Range.Text, 4, 1) & ")" & Mid(.Range.Text, 5, Len(.Range.Text) - 6)
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

But then you will lose character formatting. The following is less likely to damage existing content. If you have a lot of cells, consider turning off screen updates and creating a custom `UndoRecord` to undo all the changes with one click (especially useful when testing):

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertbraces2()
Const UndoName As String = "Undo add braces"
Dim cn As Long
Dim tn As Long
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim su As Boolean
Dim ur As Word.UndoRecord

With Application
  su = .ScreenUpdating
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  .UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord UndoName
End With

On Error GoTo finish

With ActiveDocument.Content
  For tn = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Tables(tn).Range
      For cn = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .Cells(cn)
          ' assume we only want to insert () if there are more than 3 characters in the cell
          ' strangely, the characters.count does not include the ChrW(7)
          If .Range.Characters.Count > 4 Then
            Set r = .Range
            r.Start = r.Start + 3
            r.End = r.Start
            r.Text = "("
            r.Start = r.Start + 2
            r.End = r.Start
            r.Text = ")"
            Set r = Nothing
          End If
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
End With

finish:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End If

With Application
  .UndoRecord.EndCustomRecord
  .ScreenUpdating = su
End With

End Sub
```

Writing code like this can be "as long as a piece of string". For example, do you need to process tables that are in storyranges other than the main body of the document (e.g. headers). Do you need to ensure that the braces have particular formatting, independent of the surrounding formatting? What if "character" 4 is not a character, but an inline shape or something else? What if character 4 is part of a field result or is in a protected field or locked content control? Or if it's a Unicode surrogate pair? So you may have to add bits of code to deal with specific situations that you know can occur in the scenario you are dealing with.